# Varnish working on sub-domain but not on main domain?

Tags: caching, proxies

I am using Pressflow 6 and enabled varnish caching with following settings in settings.php :

```
ini_set('arg_separator.output',     '&amp;');
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime',     0);
ini_set('magic_quotes_sybase',      0);
ini_set('session.cache_expire',     200000);
ini_set('session.cache_limiter',    'none');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  2000000);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',   200000);
ini_set('session.save_handler',     'user');
ini_set('session.use_cookies',      1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid',    0);
ini_set('url_rewriter.tags',        '');

# CDN Settings
$base_url = 'http://www.megaleecher.net';
$cookie_domain = 'megaleecher.net';

# Varnish reverse proxy on localhost
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;           
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1'); 
$conf['cache'] = 3;
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 0;
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 21600;
$conf['omit_vary_cookie'] = True;
```

When I access my sub-domain things work fine as shown below :

---

[image: Sub-domain working varnish]

---

But not on the main "www" domain, the static domain points to the same "root" and is just a placeholder to get access directly bypassing cloudflare acceleration (currently disabled to debug this issue).

---

[image: Non working varnish]

---

My varnish vcl is :

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "81";
.connect_timeout = 600s;
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 600s;

}

sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.request != "GET" &&
    req.request != "HEAD" &&
    req.request != "PUT" &&
    req.request != "POST" &&
    req.request != "TRACE" &&
    req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
    req.request != "DELETE") {
      // Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. 
      return (pipe);
  }

  if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
    // We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    return (pass);
  }

  // Remove has_js and Google Analytics cookies.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(__[a-z]+|__utma_a2a|has_js)=[^;]*", "");

  # Remove all cookies that Drupal doesn't need to know about. ANY remaining
  # cookie will cause the request to pass-through to Apache. For the most part
  # we always set the NO_CACHE cookie after any POST request, disabling the
  # Varnish cache temporarily. The session cookie allows all authenticated users
  # to pass through as long as they're logged in.
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    set req.http.Cookie = ";" req.http.Cookie;
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(SESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE)=", "; \1=");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

    if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
      # If there are no remaining cookies, remove the cookie header. If there
      # aren't any cookie headers, Varnish's default behavior will be to cache
      # the page.
      unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    else {
      # If there is any cookies left (a session or NO_CACHE cookie), do not
      # cache the page. Pass it on to Apache directly.
      return (pass);
    }
  }


  // Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
  // Remove empty cookies.
  if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }

  if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
    // Not cacheable by default 
    return (pass);
  }

  // Skip the Varnish cache for install, update, and cron
  if (req.url ~ "install\.php|update\.php|cron\.php") {
    return (pass);
  }

  // Normalize the Accept-Encoding header
  // as per: http://varnish-cache.org/wiki/FAQ/Compression
  if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
      # No point in compressing these
      remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
    elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
      set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    }
    else {
      # Unknown or deflate algorithm
      remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
  }

//Fix for global redirect
if (req.url ~ "node\?page=[0-9]+$") {
         set req.url = regsub(req.url, "node(\?page=[0-9]+$)", "\1");
         return (lookup);
     }


  // Let's have a little grace
  set req.grace = 30s;

  return (lookup);
}



// Strip any cookies before an image/js/css is inserted into cache.
sub vcl_fetch {
  if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js)$") {
    // For Varnish 2.0 or earlier, replace beresp with obj:
    // unset obj.http.set-cookie;
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }
}

// Set a header to track a cache HIT/MISS.
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
  }
  else {
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
  }
}

// In the event of an error, show friendlier messages.
sub vcl_error {
  // Redirect to some other URL in the case of a homepage failure.
  //if (req.url ~ "^/?$") {
  //  set obj.status = 302;
  //  set obj.http.Location = "http://backup.example.com/";
  //}

  // Otherwise redirect to the homepage, which will likely be in the cache.
  set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
  synthetic {"
<html>
<head>
  <title>"} obj.status " " obj.response {"</title>
  <style>
    //page {width: 400px; padding: 10px; margin: 20px auto; border: 1px solid black; background-color: //FFF;}
    p {margin-left:20px;}
    body {background-color: //DDD; margin: auto;}
    .error { margin-left: 20px; color: //222; }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/' }, 5000)">
  <div id="page">
    <h1 class="title">Page Could Not Be Loaded</h1>
    <p>The page you requested is temporarily unavailable.</p>
    <p>We're very sorry, but the page could not be loaded properly. This should be fixed very soon, and we apologize for any inconvenience.</p>
    <hr />
    <p>We're redirecting you to the <a href="/">homepage</a> in 5 seconds.</p>
    <div class="error">(Error: "} obj.status " " obj.response {")</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
"};
  return (deliver);
}
```

Comment: I am also using memcache with this setup.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two screenshots. Even the checked url is the same.

Comment: @kekkis Oops, fixed the screenshots now.

Comment: Where is your settings.php located? Is the same file being used for both subdomains (www and static)?

Comment: @kekkis Yes same codebase and same settings.php. The static domain is just a pointer.